# Multiple TLD's - .htaccess 301 Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu Server that runs Apache w/ Virtual Hosts. I run a website with the primary domain as "mydomain.com" and it's located in /var/www/mydomain.com.

Assuming I own multiple domain names (each with a different tld), what's the best way to make sure they all point to "mydomain.com" (the primary site).

In other words, is it best to create an .htaccess file in /var/www that has multiple 301 redirects for sites like "mydomain.net" and "mydomain.org" that point to "mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.org
    ServerAlias mydomain.net mydomain.info mydomain.me
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is that preferable to a 301 redirect? I read somewhere that using 301's is better for SEO to avoid duplicate content issues.

Comment: The RedirectPermanent directive causes precisely a 301 redirect, so it's ideal for SEO purposes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is the Server Alias clause needed with the RedirectPermanent? It seems like redirecting all inbound requests from / to http://mydomain.com/ would suffice. What do you think?

Comment: The ServerAlias is not necessary, it's just so that .org AND .net, .info, .me get redirected as well. You can omit it if only .org needs redirecting. And the directive "RedirectPermanent / http://www.mydomain.com/" will redirect ALL urls on .org to the corresponding one on .com, not just the root url "/" ...